# How do I access camera in react-native?

Tags: react-native

How can I access the camera with React Native? And how do I upload my own design like snapchat etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Loch Wansbrough](https://github.com/lwansbrough)'s [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) component. It is well documented and works like a charm!

Comment: This doesnt show how to add your own camera design to this?